# How can I change the new tab behaviour in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Is there any way to make new tabs behave like they do in Chrome?

In Chrome if I click the new tab button it puts the tab at the end. If I right click a tab and select "New Tab" it puts it to right of the tab I clicked on (not the end, and not to the right of the active tab).

In Firefox clicking new tab makes it appear at the end, that's fine. But by default there is no "New Tab" when you right click a tab.

I found an add-on that adds it but it opens the tabs at the end, like when you click the new tab button. I found an add-on that makes new tabs open next to the active tab but it does that even when you click the new tab button, which is annoying. And even if I could put up with it doing that, it doesn't open the tab to right of the tab I right clicked on, it opens next to the tab I have selected (the active tab).

Is there any way to make tabs work like they do in Chrome?

Comment: Why don't you use Chrome?

Comment: @HemantRupani Because I'm having issues with malware that only affects chrome (I've tried everything to get rid of it and I know what I'm doing) so I need Firefox as my backup browser even though I think chrome is much better.

Comment: I can right click on a tab and see "New Tab (After This Tab". I'm not sure which of my extensions gives this option, but it's probably [Tab Mix Plus](http://tmp.garyr.net/).

Comment: @DavidPostill Thankyou! That's exactly what I wanted! If you want to, you can add your comment as an answer and I'll vote as best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I add "New Tab" to the tab right click menu in Firefox?

The Firefox extension [Tab Mix Plus](http://tmp.garyr.net/) adds an option when right clicking on a tab:

- `New Tab (After This Tab)`.

[image]

I tested to make sure it was [Tab Mix Plus](http://tmp.garyr.net/) adding the option by disabling the extension - the option disappeared after a restart of Firefox.

Note:

The extension also offers many other tab related features and in addition adds session management.

---

#### What is Tab Mix Plus?

> Tab Mix Plus is a very popular extension for the Mozilla Firefox® browser that enhances Firefox's® tab browsing abilities. It includes such features as duplicating tabs, controlling tab focus, tab clicking options, undo closed tabs and windows, plus much more. It also includes a Session Manager with crash recovery that can save and restore combinations of opened tabs and windows.

Source [Tab Mix Plus - Introduction](http://tmp.garyr.net/support/viewpage.php?t=3&p=introduction)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Tab Mix Plus](http://tmp.garyr.net/) in any way, I am just a very satisfied end user of the software.

Comment: This add-on is perfect, thankyou!

Comment: It's one of my favourites - tab management **and** session management (better than Firefox built-in sessions) all in one extension. ;)